# Element type is invalid while trying to run app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm just getting started to learn React Native, and when I try to run my app, I get this error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> object.
>
> Check the render method of `ExpoRootComponent`.

Here is my index.js

```
/**
 * @format
 */
// import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Here is my App.js located in src/

```
import {View, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';

export default function() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.Container}>
      <Text>Welcome</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a case issue. Defined in styles as `container` but you are trying to apply `styles.Container` to view.

Comment: @scrappedcola: what do u mean? I changed from container -> Container, but still get the same error..

Comment: `<View style={styles.Container}>` but you have defined `const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{` in the provided code.

Comment: @scrappedcola: I changed from container -> Container, but i still get the same error.

Comment: Are you using Expo? You shouldn't have to register the root component yourself unless you [change the `main` field](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/#what-if-i-want-to-name-my).

Comment: @Tholle: Yes, im using Expo. So how should i do it?

Comment: Without a `main` field of your own, you should only need a [`App.js` file in the root of your project that exports a React component as default](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/templates/expo-template-bare-minimum/App.js). Pretty much what you already have, but you might need to move the `App.js` to `./` instead of `./src`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
```

Try to add this import on top of your Component